# PHP merging two arrays by Numeric Value

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have two arrays.

**$array1** :

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
      [time] => 100
      [text] => Hello
  )
  [1] => Array (
      [time] => 200
      [text] => World!
  )
  [3] => Array (
      [time] => 300
      [text] => Array1's There
  )
)
```

and more...

**$array2** :

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
      [time] => 50
      [text] => Hello
  )
  [1] => Array (
      [time] => 150
      [text] => World!
  )
  [3] => Array (
      [time] => 300
      [text] => Array2's There
  )
)
```

and more ...

**$desiredResult :**

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
      [time] => 50
      [text] => Hello
  )
  [1] => Array (
      [time] => 100
      [text] => Hello
  )
  [2] => Array (
      [time] => 150
      [text] => World
  )
  [3] => Array (
      [time] => 200
      [text] => World
  )
  [4] => Array (
      [time] => 300
      [text] => Array1's There
  )
  [5] => Array (
      [time] => 300
      [text] => Array2's There
  )
)
```

I need to merge two array by time's numeric value, and if time's value the same, Array1's data first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With below code you will get the result you want.

```
$finalArray = array();
if(count($array1) == count($array2)){
  for ($icount = 0; $icount < count($array1); $icount++) {
    if( ($array1[$icount] < $array2[$icount]) || ($array1[$icount] == $array2[$icount])){
      $finalArray[] = $array1[$icount];
      $finalArray[] = $array2[$icount];
    } else if($array1[$icount] > $array2[$icount]){
      $finalArray[] = $array2[$icount];
      $finalArray[] = $array1[$icount];
    }
  }
}
```

Also i have created function which can gives you result if anyone array contains more value then other array.

```
function mapArray($array1, $array2, $minCount, $maxCount, $maxCountFrom = ''){
  for ($icount = 0; $icount < $minCount; $icount++) {
    if( ($array1[$icount] < $array2[$icount]) || ($array1[$icount] == $array2[$icount])){
      $finalArray[] = $array1[$icount];
      $finalArray[] = $array2[$icount];
    } else if($array1[$icount] > $array2[$icount]){
      $finalArray[] = $array2[$icount];
      $finalArray[] = $array1[$icount];
    }
  }

  if(!empty($maxCountFrom)){
    if($maxCountFrom == '1'){
      for ($jcount = $icount; $jcount < $maxCount; $jcount++) {
        $finalArray[] = $array1[$jcount];
      }
    } else if($maxCountFrom == '2'){
      for ($jcount = $icount; $jcount < $maxCount; $jcount++) {
        $finalArray[] = $array2[$jcount];
      }
    }
  }
  return $finalArray;
}

$array1Count = count($array1);
$array2Count = count($array2);
if($array1Count > $array2Count){
  $result = mapArray($array1, $array2, $array2Count, $array1Count, '1');
} elseif($array1Count < $array2Count){
  $result = mapArray($array1, $array2, $array1Count, $array2Count, '2');
} elseif($array1Count == $array2Count){
  $result = mapArray($array1, $array2, $array2Count, $array2Count);
}
```

In this function where you can pass `2 array`, `count of the both array` by `minimum` count and `maximum` count, and last parameter is to define which `array has maximum value` and from that array fetch all the remaining values to the `final array`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
[time]'s value are irregular and I want merge two array by key [time]'s value in ascending order.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I just put it together and sort merged array by time's value in ascending order. Thanks @Yogendrasinh

Comment: Or you can add change in code by this line as `$array1[$icount]['time']` when comparing in if condition.